# File structure of a Procedural C++ program

Tags: c++, structure, file-structure

I am new to c++ and am writing a procedural program to get the hang of that side of it.  I will have a collections of functions that call each other and some include statements, namespace statements, and constant declarations.

My questions are:

What are some guidelines for the file structure of the program ? Should I break this apart with some functions in another file(s) if so are their some standards for what categories of functions deserve their own file?

I hope this question is specific enough. I am NOT looking for the "best" way to do this, just some general guidelines people use.

Thanks so much.

Comment: When you so shopping do you put the bleach in with the chess, etc. Do they split themselves up a bit as into logical units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should group your procedures in some kind of logic and put them together in one file. Then it's a lot easier to read code and it's much more elegant than having only a few extensive files. A good practice is also to make declarations of functions at the top of the file and their definitions at the bottom.

```
//declarations
void myfun(int a);
/...

//definitions
void myfun(int a)
{
//do sth
}
```

Comment: So organize them in some sort of way but keep them in one file? I was originally leaning that way but, I wanted to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: If they relate to the same thing then yes